# Storing multiple array values as a JSON column in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to store form values from a set of fields that share the same name into a `JSON` column type.

---

```
<?php
//Form values as an array
$title = request('title');
$price = request('price');
$link = request('link');

 $arrM = array();

 for($i = 0; $i < count($title); $i++) {
    $arrM[] = array(
       'title' => $title[$I], 
       'price' => $price[$I],
       'link' => $link[$i],    
    );
 }

 Tag::create([
  'title' => request('title'),
  'tag_points' => $arrM,
 ]);
```

I have taken each value and combined into an array and set the cast as an `array`. Laravel will not accept the format below

**$arrM - Output**

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "First Title"
    "price" => "10"
    "link" => "https://google.com"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Second Title"
    "price" => "40"
    "link" => "https://stackoverflow.com"
  ]
]
```

**Error**

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given`

**How I'd like it to be stored in DB column**

```
[{
    "title": "First Title",
    "price": "10",
    "link": "https://google.com"
}, {
    "title": "Second Title",
    "price": "40",
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com"
}]
```

Comment: I found the issue - I was using the same `title` field while testing for the title of the post which was causing multiple values entering on the string field!

Answer (score 0):

To store JSON fields, in your migrations, you must do something like:

```
$table->json('field')
```

Then in if you want to fetch those values, you must cast this value from JSON to Array. You can do that by using the $casts property.

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'field' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Comment: hey! - I have already set these I'm afraid. The issue is it's not storing with the current code.